# Asp.net Validations and controls

Tags: asp.net

how to disable the (Required attribute) in Text box in ASP.NET web forms
I want to change the web form page to another one when I click on the  Login button but I cant!
please help!

Answer (score 2):

For Disable Validation :

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt" runat="server"  causesvalidation="false" />  // or reqiured=false
```

For Redirect :

```
protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.Redirect("YourPage.aspx");
//or
Server.Transfer("YourPage.aspx");
}
```